# Designing polymorphic subclasses so that new ones can be easily added without redeploying

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns, anti-patterns, extensibility, ooad

I am redesigning an application that is used for data acquisition.
We have a base class called `Sensor` which is more or less as follows:

```
public abstract class Sensor
{
    public virtual String Name { get; }
    public virtual UnitOfMeasurement Unit { get; }
    public virtual int SamplingRate { get; }
    public virtual CalibrationModel Calibration { get; }
}
```

Each of its subclasses has a "hardcoded" value for each property. For example `EmgSensor` has "EMG" as Name, "UnitOfMeasurement.Volt" as Unit, etc.

Our current system has this problem I am trying to solve: Each time that a new actual sensor hardware is developed and added to our portfolio, we need to do the following "shotgun surgery":

1. Create a new `Sensor` subclass;
2. Perform some scattered, minor changes on the rest of the system (due to depencencies, etc.);
3. Release an update to our client base.

I understand that each physical sensor (the hardware) is a conceptual unit, and as such should be able to be "plugged" to a running system so that it doesn't need to be recompiled.

On the other hand, if each subtype of `Sensor` is to be considered a class, how could I create a "dynamic" class from, say, configuration files? Should I be using the Factory pattern? Is there any other, more suitable way of achieving what I need?

I am using C# (although I think this is incidental to the question).

Answer (score 1):

.NET makes it very easy to dynamically load types.  What I've done is just define a folder where I drop assemblies that contain new sensors. I have a loader class that loads the assemblies in the folder, and then checks them for subclasses of Sensor, creates instances of the subclasses and returns them in a list.

The CoreLibrary assembly holds the abstract base class (and anything else it needs)

```
namespace CoreLibrary
{
    public abstract class Sensor
    {
        public abstract String Name { get; }
        public abstract UnitOfMeasurement Unit { get; }
        public abstract int SamplingRate { get; }
        public abstract CalibrationModel Calibration { get; }
    }
}
```

DynamicClassLoader is the assembly that has the loader class that does fun stuff.  It references the CoreLibrary...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Configuration;
using CoreLibrary;

namespace DynamicClassLoader
{
    public class Loader
    {
        public List<Sensor> LoadDynamicSensors()
        {
            var sensors = new List<Sensor>();
            if (!Directory.Exists(DynamicAssemblyFolder))
            {
                return sensors;
            }
            var dllFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(DynamicAssemblyFolder, "*.dll");

            foreach (var dllFileName in dllFileNames)
            {
                var dynamicAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFileName);
                foreach (var sensorType in dynamicAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Sensor))))
                {
                    var sensor = (Sensor)Activator.CreateInstance(sensorType);
                    sensors.Add(sensor);
                }
            }
            return sensors;
        }

        public string DynamicAssemblyFolder
        {
            get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DynamicAssemblyFolder"]; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just make assemblies that reference the CoreLibrary and drop their dlls in the defined folder. For instance...

```
using CoreLibrary;

namespace DynamicOne
{
    public class SensorA: Sensor
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            get { return  "Sensor A"; }
        }

        public override UnitOfMeasurement Unit
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public override int SamplingRate
        {
            get { return 10; }
        }

        public override CalibrationModel Calibration
        {
            get { return  null; }
        }
    }
}
```

And to show it works a console app. It only references CoreLibrary and the DynamicClassLoader. It needs no reference to the dynamically loaded assemblies, as the types are all derived from Sensor.

```
using System;
using DynamicClassLoader;

namespace DynamicLoading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var loader = new Loader();
            var sensors = loader.LoadDynamicSensors();
            Console.WriteLine(loader.DynamicAssemblyFolder);
            foreach (var sensor in sensors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sensor.Name);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

When a new type is needed.  Create a new assembly, drop it in the designated folder and restart the app and the new sensor is loaded and ready to go.  (You could get fancy with a file watcher and do it automatically, but that might be overkill.)

Not sure how you use the sensors once you have them, but you could wrap (or inject) the loader in a factory, to make it easy to get a specific one.